# How to license a server with two processors, 16 cores and Windows Server 2016 Standard?

Tags: windows-server-2016, licensing

I'm a bit confused by the Windows Server 2016 per core licensing model. I've a server with two processors and 16 cores, which I want to use as a Hyper-V host with 5 guests.

Now I can buy [Windows Server 2016 Standard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M1L0YJL) licenses for 16 cores. So it means I've licensed all cores. From each Windows Server Standard license I can get two virtualized machines. So I buy two additional licenses to cover the 5 guests?

Comment: Have you thought about a data centre license?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be more expensive for 5 guests compared to the Standard license. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah upon checking yeah you are right. Important thing is that in order to get the additional two VM rights you need to fulfil the core licensing requirements again. I.e you’ll need to license 16 cores 4 times. To get 6 VM licensing rights.